# SSMS 2018 How to create query that display tables with DBA defined columns and tables that are not empty

Tags: sql-server

I am a power bi user, my current task was to do custom "views" on Microsoft SQL database so that those "views" can be used in doing power bi report later.

Now there's one problem that i have encountered, I have a long list of tables that can't be disclosed and each of the table has a list of columns bound to them.

I did like to request for help, I need to search tables that are not empty but with custom defined columns.

Let's say I have tableA, tableB, tableC and tableD.

I want to first search let's say a custom column named "UserID" but I don't want it to displayed yet, I want to do 2nd filter that filters out the table that are empty.

So the end result was only the tables that are not empty and tables that have the column named UserID

Is it possible to do this, and if yes, can I request for the query to get the result I want?

Comment: Will need more information.  Are all columns to be returned from all tables that aren't empty?  If a table is empty, no data will be returned, so why is there a need to filter it out--perhaps so that its unique columns will not be displayed?  Should the output be one unioned set, or a set from each table?

Comment: SELECT o.NAME,
  i.rowcnt 
FROM sysindexes AS i
  INNER JOIN sysobjects AS o ON i.id = o.id 
  INNER JOIN sys.all_columns AS c ON o.id = c.object_id
WHERE i.indid < 2  
 AND OBJECTPROPERTY(o.id, 'IsMSShipped') = 0
 AND c.name = 'UserID'
 AND i.rowcnt > 0
ORDER BY o.NAME